# Template Haskell - Static Assert

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I've written the following function:

```
staticAssert :: Bool -> Q [Dec]
staticAssert cond = case cond of
    True -> return []
    False -> fail "staticAssert failed"
```

Basically this evaluates condition at compile time and if it is false causes a compile error.

However, what I would like for `staticAssert` to instead of outputting "staticAssert failed", output the expression that failed the assertion.

Comment: If you write `$(fail "err")`, then the error will include the source file, line and column number, for example, I get `test.hs:8:3: err`. If you want to access the source position to print it in some custom way, us `Language.Haskell.TH.location`

Comment: Sorry you're right. Now just to print the expression?

Comment: You mean print the result of `location`? `$(location >>= fail . show)` (`Loc` doesn't have a show instance so you'll have to write or derive it yourself)

Comment: No, I mean print the expression being tested.

Comment: Which expression is that? Your function has type `Bool -> Q [Dec]`.

Comment: The bool part. I assume the signature will need to be changed. E.g. "Assertion failed: 2+2=5"

Comment: How about `assert bool str = if not bool then fail $ "Assertion failed: " ++ str else return []`

Comment: Then I'd have to write `assert (2 + 2 == 5) "(2 + 2 == 5)"`. This is error prone and violates Don't Repeat Yourself.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want `location` from [Language.Haskell.TH](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.8.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH.html).